# ActionController::ParameterMissing / param is missing or the value is empty: poll Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm coding a Quizz generator solution with RoR and when I want to insert data on my 'Poll' table I have a

My Poll.rb model

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :formulaire
end
```

My Poll table :

```
create_table "polls", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "formulaire_id"
  t.integer  "question_id"
  t.integer  "answer_id"
  t.string   "nom"
  t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
end
```

My Polls_controller.rb

```
def poll_params
   params.require(:poll).permit(:formulaire_id, :question_id, :answer_id,:nom) 
end
```

I first tried this on my view :

```
<% for question in @formulaire.questions %>

    <li> 
    <%=h question.nom %> 
    <ul>
    <% for answer in question.answers %>


        <%= radio_button("poll", "answer_id", answer.id) %>  <%=h answer.content %> <br/>
        <% %> 
    <% end %>

    </ul>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

But I could just insert one answer on my DB for all my questions

I tried this :

```
 <%= form_for([@formulaire, @formulaire.polls.new]) do |f| %>
   <%  i = 0 %>
      <% for question in @formulaire.questions %>

    <li> 
    <%=h question.nom %> 
    <ul>

    <% for answer in question.answers %>

        <%= radio_button("poll"+i.to_s, "answer_id", answer.id) %>  <%=h answer.content %> <br/>

    <% end %>
             <% i=i+1 %>  
    </ul>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

But I have this error : **ActionController::ParameterMissing in PollsController#create
  param is missing or the value is empty: poll**

How can I handle this. Thank you

Comment: lets try the given solution below and let me know for further guidance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
<%= radio_button("poll"+i.to_s, "answer_id", answer.id) %>  <%=h answer.content %> <br/>
```

with

```
<%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id%>
```

as your params should hit action like  - `params[:poll][:answer_id]` but  by you are giving the name of radio button "`poll"` which will hit server with `params[:poll]`

final code should like this:

```
 <%= form_for @formulaire.polls.new, url: your_path, method: :post, :html => { id: "your_id", class: "your_class"} do |f| %>
   <%@formulaire.questions.each do |question|%>
     <%=h question.nom %>
     <%question.answers.each do |answer|%>
       <%= f.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id%> <%=h answer.content %> <br/>
     <%end%>
   <%end%>
 <%end%>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because I have several questions with several choices and I can check a unique choice for all of my questions. I want to check a unique choice for each question.

Comment: @user9007028 exactly that i have explained in answer  kindly look back, for each question i have looped through the choices and that choice will be sent on submission of form by radion button.

Comment: It's the same problem, and your form_for bring me a 'undefined method `polls_path'' error. So I left my <%= form_for(@formulaire.polls.new) do |f| %>
But I can check juste one answer for all of my choices for all of my questions.

Comment: Do you see where my problem is ?

Comment: @user9007028 if it doesn't  get the right path then use `url: your_path` with form_for. hope you get it. you can get the path by run the rake routes on console. hope you get it,

Comment: @user9007028 i have modified the answer, let me know for further guidance. if it helped you, feel free to upvote/accept answer. thank you

Comment: Thank you @gabbar, can you take a look at this topic pls? It's a similar problem that I have. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337284/rails-1-radio-button-adding-multiple-information-in-database